# .find not working on td loaded after DOM

Tags: jquery, web

So, I have this table:

```
<div id="notes" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="note-table">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

... and I load table elements after the DOM, has been loaded; so the table looks like this:

```
<div id="notes" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="note-table">
                           <tr><td>This is a test</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My jQuery code is this, but it doesn't work.

```
$('#note-table').on("click", "td", function(){
      var row = $(this).find('td:first').addClass("success");
});
```

(the success class is a bootstrap class, fyi)

The `var row =` line was one that I repurposed from another part of my code that works fine. However, it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clicking on the table cell: So `.find()` will not find a table cell. This `.on("click", "td", function()`, is delegating the click to the table cell (`td`). http://api.jquery.com/on/  `$(this)` is `td`.

You would want to do something like this:

```
if($(this).is(':first-child')) {
      $(this).addClass("success");
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/kxonfppz/8/

Comment: I get an "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is(...).addClass is not a function" I tried removing the var row part, but that does nothing.

Comment: Sorry. I had that partially wrong. Updated my answer.